# How to insert a database into an Android application

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have created a database which contains 4 tables using Firefox plugin. The format of the saved database is `.sqlite`(`name.sqlite`).

I just want to know how/where to insert it into the android project that I am developing and what the  changes are that I should make in my project (like changes in the Manifest file). I guess I should paste it into an asset folder, but I do not know how to access it in the code.

I want to `add`, `view`, `update` and `delete` data in the table, how should Ido this? Or Should I use another way?

Comment: You could do that but I don't recommend you to because that's not how Android works. You need to programmatically create your tables. [Check the Android documentation for more details](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Comment: You are welcome to [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for packaging a database with your app.

Comment: I tried SQLiteAssetHelper but it show runtime exception as (unable to start activity ComponentInfo dom.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: missing databases/U_Project.sqlitefile.. or target file is not writable..)  I save U_Project.sqlitefile in asset file....

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty solid tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Basically, don't copy your sqlite file directly into the project. Follow the steps and create / upgrade your database in the provided onCreate and onUpgrade hooks.

These hooks give you the opportunity to change your database structure when publishing updates through the Play Store.

And the proper places to do longer running operations to upgrade all your data, or prefill your data from disk/network.

If you want to prefill your DB from a dataset, you can provide that data in a raw XML, or JSON, or CSV, and after your onCreate do all the inserts when the app launches from a fresh install.

Comment: My problem is that I have a database that has to be installed with the  application, which contains some values...

Comment: Exactly, which you can do. Throw the values into the table you create from a raw xml file during the initial onCreate call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some good tuts for sqlite...

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/using-sqlite-in-android-a-really-simple-example/

http://androidexample.com/SQLite_Database_Manipulation_Class_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=51

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Answer cannot consist in links only.

Comment: I know how to create and use sqlite in code but my problem is I donot know who to insert and read from the database I stored in asset folder